# ANTLR test class not compiling?

Tags: antlr

I've cobbled together some code to test a lexer/parser grammar but I'm a stuck on how to create the appropriate file input / stream objects to parse a file. My code is as follows, and I'm getting an error about giving the BasicLexer class constructor an ANTLRInputStream instead of a CharStream, and a similar message with giving the BasicParser a CommonTokenStream (it expects TokenStream). Any ideas on where I've gone wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String filename = args[0];
    InputStream is;

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(filename);

        //is.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ANTLRInputStream in = new ANTLRInputStream(is);
    BasicLexer lexer = new BasicLexer(in);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    BasicParser parser = new BasicParser(tokens);
    parser.eval();
}
```

Comment: think you should move your code up into the try block - as there is a chance "is" may not be valid in your call to the ANTLRInputStream constructor

Comment: If the `FileInputStream` throws an exception, the `ANTLRInputStream` is going to have no value for `is`. Just move everything from `ANTLRInputStream` until `eval()` to the `try` block.

Comment: You guys are right. Also my apparent type of the ANTLRInputStream was wrong, it had to be CharStream, and I had to change parser.eval() to parser.expr().